# Update react native ui component on data changes throughout the application from a single data source

Tags: react-native, redux

I am new to react-native, I am getting data from server and on the basis of data I have to update my UI element just like change the background colour or hide the image. To achieve this what approach should I follow, right now I am trying to do it using redux but somehow unable to update the particular item in redux, because in redux I am storing Json data. I tried to update but still no luck to update the redux.

basically I want to update my UI in every screen if I get any data from server automatically like notification or other.

Please help me to decide better approach to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^5.0.3",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.4.1",
    "react-native": "0.56.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.8.0",
    "react-native-navigation": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-segmented-control-tab": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-size-matters": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^6.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "5.0.2",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.4.1"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Redux, Try to make component based on its state. Suppose you want to change the color of the component. You can do it as to make component color dynamic using the prop, on state change dispatch action and reducer will return the new state to the component. the component should render based on that state.
Check out [How Redux Works](https://blog.usejournal.com/how-does-redux-work-b1cce46d4fa6) Article and you will get it.

Comment: Hi @Kiran, thanks for the response, I will check your solution and According to your  Redux Article, I found that it is adding TODO using ADD_TODO action type as it's  nested array. Can you please suggestion how I can update the existing ToDo using any todo-id ??

Comment: Search that TODO from the array and edit it. dispatch it as new data to component and you will be good to go.